# Ruta no encontrada Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy intentando colocar una ruta en un menú, pero me da un error de ruta no encontrada

> Route [experience/create] not defined.

Llamo a la ruta de la siguiente manera

```html
<x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('experience/create') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('experience/create')">
    {{ __('Create Experience') }}
</x-jet-nav-link>
```

Defino la ruta

```html
Route::resource('experience', ExperienceController::class);
```

He probado a hacer un `php artisan route:cache` y `php artisan route:list` y veo que las rutas están listadas

```html
GET|HEAD | experience | experience.index | App\Http\Controllers\ExperienceController@index | web
POST | experience | experience.store | App\Http\Controllers\ExperienceController@store | web
GET|HEAD | experience/create | experience.create | App\Http\Controllers\ExperienceController@create | web
DELETE | experience/{experience}| experience.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\ExperienceController@destroy | web
```

Comment: No sé qué versión de Laravel estés ocupando, pero te sugeriría nombrar tus rutas y de ese modo llamarlas dentro de tus archivos blade. Por ejemplo, dale un nombre a esta ruta como: `Route::resource('experience', ExperienceController::class)->name("experience.create");` y luego llamarla como `href="{{ route("experience.create") }}"` la cual apuntará dentro de tu aplicativo a `/experience`

Comment: El nombre de la ruta es `experience.create` y no `experience/create`. Te lo muestra cuando haces el `php artisan route:list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El helper **route()** recibe como parametro el **name** rutas de tal forma que debes cambiar **experience/create** por **experience.create** ya que este último es el **name** de tu ruta, y puedes ver su nombre cuando haces un **php artisan route:list** en la columna **name** y que **experience/create** esta mal escrito ya que el nombre lleva un punto y no una barra, quedaria de esta forma:

```
<x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('experience.create') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('experience/create')">
    {{ __('Create Experience') }}
</x-jet-nav-link>
```